# Cleaner way to write copy and past loop code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA code that copies specific cells from a row based on a set of criteria as it loops through a range.  The code below works just find, I am wondering if there a cleaner way to build it?

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

With ThisWorkbook
 Set sh2 = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
 sh2.Name = "Upload"
 sh2.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
 sh2.Range("B1").Value = "Ledger Acct"
 sh2.Range("C1").Value = "Department"
 sh2.Range("D1").Value = "Cost Center"
 sh2.Range("E1").Value = "Purpose"
 sh2.Range("F1").Value = "Account Name"
 sh2.Range("G1").Value = "Transaction Text"
 sh2.Range("H1").Value = "Line Amount"
 sh2.Range("I1").Value = "Currency"
End With

Set sh1 = Sheets("Remaining for Uploads")

'This will find the last used row in a column A on sh1'
    With sh1
       LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

'First row number where the values will be pasted in Upload'
    With sh2
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

 For i = 2 To LastRow
    With sh1
       If Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 7))) And Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 8))) And   Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 9))) And Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 10))) Then
           .Cells(i, 7).Copy
            sh2.Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, 8).Copy
            sh2.Range("C" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, 9).Copy
            sh2.Range("D" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, 10).Copy
            sh2.Range("E" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, 13).Copy
            sh2.Range("H" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           j = j + 1
       End If
   End With
Next i
```

Comment: Don't actually copy/paste. You can directly assign a value to a cell. Your first one would be `sh2.Range("B" & j) = .Cells(i, 7)`. I would also move your `With..EndWith`outside the loop. There is no need for it to be inside, and I believe you are taking away some of the benefit having it inside.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to tighten up the code. 1) You can use an Array to load your headers. 2) You can just set two ranges equal to each other if you just need the values.  Also, I'm a fan of `With` statements too, but since you just need them once for the `lastRow` and `j`, I just put the sheet before the range references to save four lines.

```
Sub t()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim headers() As Variant
headers = Array("Date", "Ledger Acct", "Department", "Cost Center", "Purpose", "Account Name", "Transaction Text", "Line Amount", "Currency")

With ThisWorkbook
    Set sh2 = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    sh2.Name = "Upload"
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        sh2.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = headers(i) 'i + 1 because arrays start with 0 index, not 1.
    Next i
End With

Set sh1 = Sheets("Remaining for Uploads")

'This will find the last used row in a column A on sh1'
LastRow = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'First row number where the values will be pasted in Upload'
j = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range

With sh1
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Set copyRng = .Range(.Cells(i, 7), .Cells(i, 10))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(copyRng) = 4 Then ' use COUNTA() to count cells that are not empty
            Union(sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(j, 2), sh2.Cells(j, 5)), sh2.Cells(j, 8)).Value = Union(copyRng, .Cells(i, 13)).Value
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End With 'sh1
End Sub
```

Also, no need to do the 4 `If Not IsEmpty()` lines. Just do a `COUNTA()` and if that equals for, then you know that range has 4 non-empty cells.

Comment: Good call with the Array and COUNTA().  Thanks for the advice, this makes much more sense.

Comment: @JBurgess - Does it work for you? Or does it error/not copy just what you needed? I got a little turned around in the `For i= 2 to LastRow` loop, but I think it is correct...